# Revoking public keys

Tags: keystore

I am starting to play around with Ethereum  and smart contracts.

I was wondering is there is a way in Eth to revoke or kill of a public key you have given out?

If so, will the other party be notified or can it be done without their knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot delete a public key once it has been provided. Why? It's '**public**'.

If you are concerned of your wallet(read: private key), then you might want to remove that particular key from you usage and move funds stored in it to a new one.

Comment: Well i was thinking more on the lines of using the blockchain as a storage medium for sensitive information. So lets say i have a file that i control with the private key and i give you a public key for viewing. But i was thinking on a conditional layer were i could say after x time after being issue, this public key is no longer valid.

Comment: I could see an application of transient cryptography here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transient-key_cryptography